# Getting values not list for cons in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, cons

I'm making a function in scheme(lisp) in which I need to cons a list with it reverse, as below:

```
(cons list (cdr (reverse list)))
```

consider I have this list '(0 1 2), the desired output would be:

```
(0 1 2 1 0)
```

but I get:

```
((0 1 2) 1 0)
```

is there any function that returns the values of the list, not the list itself?

Comment: Looks like homework. Remember that lists consist of pairs. Draw a picture of your list, its reverse and result you want as pairs - it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on `cons`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons

`cons` will pair an element with another. If you pair an element with a list, you are adding this element at the beginning of the list. In your case, the element you are pairing to your reversed list is itself a list. See the examples on the wiki page.

What you want here is `append`, since you want to concatenate those two lists together.

Answer (score 0):

Append it like this:

```
(define (mirror ls)
    (if (null? (cdr ls))
        ls
        (let ((x (car ls)))
            (append 
                (list x)
                (mirror (cdr ls))
                (list x)))))
```

Hope it helps :)